# Ceiling Fan light enclosure - CFL only lights

Tags: ceiling-fan, led, cfl

We have a few ceiling fans at home with an enclosed lighting. There's a sticker inside it saying 2X20W max, CFL lights only. What is the reason they are restricted to CFL light only? I tried putting some LED lights on it and it seems to work fine (10.5W and 9W LED lights). 
The base of the LED lights is significantly hotter but everything else seems to be same temperature as CFL lights. Am i doing something wrong if i put LED lights with the "CFL only" restriction?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Any guess as to how old the fans are?

Answer (score 1):

Typically the reason for the low wattage rating is because of small gauge wire used in the fixture that would not be rated for much higher wattage/current draw required by 40 or 60 watt incandescent bulbs. Incandescent or halogen bulbs burn much hotter and in an enclosed space can fail prematurely. As far as using LED bulbs, they should work fine. The draw is very low and the heat is not much more than CFLs. I have been using LED bulbs in enclosed fixtures for a few years now with no problems.

Comment: Some LED bulbs are happier in enclosed fixtures than others; read the package labelling. But the worst that's likely to happen is that they fail earlier than they should.

Comment: True, some of the cheaper led's have inferior amps that heat up more than quality ones.